# SetContentView() taking time even though layout is very simple and light

Tags: android, android-layout

My `setContentView()` is taking around 3 seconds to load even though it has very simple layout withouht any custom views.

xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/homeScreenLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_home"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeButtonsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnHomeSearch"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/some_drawable" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHomeSearch"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/btnHomeSearch"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Some text"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnHomeClip"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/some_drawable" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHomeClip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/btnHomeClip"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Some text"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSeeAll"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/some_drawable" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/btnSeeAll"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Some text"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Below is the piece of onCreate():

```
Log.i("PN","Main onCreate() start");
setContentView(R.layout.main_flipper);
Log.i("PN","Main onCreate() aftr setContentView");
```

this `ViewFlipper` has only 2 layouts. 2nd layout is also lightweight.

---

Corresponding Log:

```
11-12 09:23:01.622: I/PN(12081): Main onCreate() start
11-12 09:23:04.324: I/PN(12081): Main onCreate() aftr setContentView
```

Note that `setContentView()` is taking approx 3 seconds which is quite high.

Any idea why this is happening?

Any help appreciated.

### Edit

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        Log.i("PN","Main onCreate() start");
        // Set the design screen for the code
        // Activate full screen for this flow
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_flipper);
        Log.i("PN","Main onCreate() aftr setContentView");

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        Log.i("PN","Main onCreate() aftr getExtras");
        int viewNo = 0;
        if (b != null) {
            viewNo = b.getInt("View");
        }

        initVariables();

        setOnClickListeners();
        initSearchView();
        setTextWatcher();
        vf.setDisplayedChild(viewNo);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

updated Log:

```
11-12 09:42:12.532: I/PN(14342): Main onCreate() start = 1384249332537
11-12 09:42:15.122: I/PN(14342): Main onCreate() aftr setContentView = 1384249335125
11-12 09:42:15.142: I/PN(14342): Main onCreate() aftr getExtras = 1384249335142
11-12 09:42:15.142: I/PN(14342): Main onCreate() b4 init = 1384249335142
11-12 09:42:15.392: I/PN(14342): Main onCreate() End = 1384249335396
```

As we can see, main delay is happening in setting up `setContentView()`

### Edit (2)

updated Log:

```
11-12 09:48:11.342: I/PN(15081): Main onCreate() start = 1384249691345
11-12 09:48:11.372: I/PN(15081): Main onCreate() aftr FLAG_FULLSCREEN = 1384249691372
11-12 09:48:13.961: I/PN(15081): Main onCreate() aftr setContentView = 1384249693970
```

Comment: since you have many different layout inside a single layout, it takes more time.try to reduce no of layout which is always advisable will reduce loading time

Comment: Logs are asynchronous. Try to calculate to the times it takes. Do you have any other code in the onCreate? Are you subclassing Activity ?

Comment: No @krishna I have used a lot more complex layouts and it did not even take a second to load. This layout should not take any time at all. Please show your whole onCreate method and maybe use System.currentTimeMillis() to log times for start and end.

Comment: @krishna: `ViewFlipper` is having only 2 layouts. 2nd layout is also lightweight.

Comment: Try removing the window requests before the setContentView and see if that makes a difference. What device are you using?

Comment: @blackbelt: pls check updated log.

Comment: @Neil : code added and No,it doesn't make any diff. Also, you can see from Log, `setContentView()` is consuming most of the time.

Comment: try again commenting out requestingWindowFeatures and getWindow().setFlag

Comment: @blackbelt : pls check Edit (2)

Comment: @Neil: m trying on Emulator right now, but it takes long time on real device also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needs to unload item by item to see which is the cause.
My suggestion:

1. Remove background drawables and test.
2. Remove each of the 3rd layer relative layout and test.

p/s: I think You can actually reduce one layer of relative layout. The second layer of relative layout could be merged with the first one.

Comment: I'll test that. About 2 layers, you can notice `android:id="@+id/mainview"` in 2nd layer. if I place that in 1st layer, then while using `findViewById()`, it returns null